How to execute a previous pipeline run in Azure Data Factory
We have a situation where a previous pipeline failed. For example the pipeline failed on a particular date, however since that date the pipeline has been working perfectly fine.
The problem is we need to execute the pipeline from a past date.
Because each pipeline has it own Activity run ID is it possible to execute a previous pipeline with that unique Activity run ID?
In our case the pipeline that was executed on a particular day has an Activity run ID is: 3077a0db-9c0f-4ac4-a890-42553fcad2f8
Can we execute the pipeline with that ID:



Can we execute the pipeline with that ID

AFAIK, it might not be possible to run a pipeline run again because there might be some modifications in the pipeline and the new pipeline run will be always takes the latest published pipeline. Also, every pipeline run id and activity run id will be unique and, on every trigger of the pipeline it will only runs the latest published pipeline.
If your pipeline is the same without any modifications and you want to run the same pipeline run again, you can use the re-run option. But this also, will run the last published pipeline and if your activities involve any dynamic operations related to date, it will only work as per the current date.
You can re-run a pipeline like below in the ADF pipeline monitor.

The new pipeline runs will be linked to the old pipeline run and all pipelines run ids are different and unique

You can also re-run a pipeline from the failed activity as well.


Hi Rakesh, please use the built-in image uploader to host images on Stack Overflow's image domain, rather than uploading them to imgur, to avoid issues with your images not being visible to some readers.

Hi @RakeshGovindula, if I 'Rerun from the failed activity' will the pipeline run with the latest published pipeline with new modifications

Yes, it will run latest published pipeline.
